# Why does looping over column in dataframe before parsing leads to indexing error, Python 3.6+?

Tags: python, regex, dataframe, loops, parsing

This is following a previous post ([regex match not working on simple string with Pyteomics parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66483290/regex-match-not-working-on-simple-string-with-pyteomics-parser/66496859#66496859))

I have generated a dataframe (pep_df) of >50,000 strings from 20,000 strings. However what I am looking to do now is parse the str into individual characters and return these lists into the dictionary (pep_dict). I keep getting an error: [image: Error]

**Here is a sample of the dataframe:**

```
{'sequence': {0: 'VISYGGCVAQLFIFLALGSTECLLLAVMCFDR',
  1: 'TEQGDSAAYLR',
  2: 'DSLQVSK',
  3: 'GSDALSETSSVSHIEDLEK',
  4: 'QTDPQSSSAK',
  5: 'IFGFQAGLTSLDCSGSYCLPVPVIPSFSTALYGK',
  6: 'YQTEAVEMMDQIVHWVQEDASGLGRPQLQGAPAAEPMAVPMMLLNLVEQLGEADEELAGK',
  7: 'QLEFAAQYPPTFDR',
  8: 'EWPGDLYNNSVIVQAVR',
  9: 'QIWHPNQTCDAAR',
  10: 'YEHAFESSQK',
  11: 'FISQWCGGLPSTSFSFQ',
  12: 'QPSAFIVTQHPLPNTVK',
  13: 'EVASNSELVQSSR',
  14: 'ISHVSGYNYGIPHSCIR',
  15: 'NALQYIHDGSSTR',
  16: 'LDGGSGSTSSSGCHPGGAR',
  17: 'LSLDQALVK',
  18: 'ASAELLR',
  19: 'SDSGPYPLTAR',
  20: 'MGYFLPDDYK',
  21: 'TEIQTLFK',
  22: 'VFQPSVPATK',
  23: 'ETVPSMETGDLCADTAPTPK',
  24: 'GDDCLMK',
  25: 'EGHCLAQDVEEQAR',
  26: 'FEEITGVINPALDK',
  27: 'STSTPTSPGPR',
  28: 'ELPLHGR',
  29: 'YIIIGDMGVGK',
  30: 'TTCCCPSCCVSSCCRPQCCQSVCCQPTCCRPSCCISSCCHPSCCESSCCRPCCCVRPVCGR',
  31: 'VTTFEHQYVSAIK',
  32: 'VVSHPSGVLELHMK',
  33: 'NITFDACLIQMFLIHFFSMMESGILLAMSFDR',
  34: 'YPVPEESQEGTFVGNVAQDFLLDTDSLSAR',
  35: 'HVVMELK',
  36: 'VQWGLVMCFLSYFGTFAVEFR',
  37: 'FEGGAEGR',
  38: 'NLSALSDWYSVYTSAIAFTVYMNAVWHGWAIPLFLFLAILR',
  39: 'TFSYGSSLIQHR',
  40: 'TNTTAVGISKPANIHVK',
  41: 'VPQLGPR',
  42: 'TDDCHPWVLPVVK',
  43: 'LCCAGHDR',
  44: 'QQYLCQPLLDAVLANIR',
  45: 'IYEQLPEVQK',
  46: 'LYLTQAAGLEVPPEEMSLELPETHIEEK',
  47: 'TIEDFESMNTYLQTSPSSVFTSK',
  48: 'AGSVFGEISLLAAGGGNR',
  49: 'QTIIGQPMSVTITTK',
  50: 'ASDQCLK',
  51: 'KPPGELLVSLEELEK',
  52: 'ALSQPSSYSPSCTSSK',
  53: 'LCPYFFANQEFYSLDSQLPIWGVR',
  54: 'QFYEEELINSVVISQLSHIPEDK',
  55: 'IEPMLETLENLSSR',
  56: 'DALQLEMSLVQAR',
  57: 'CHCGEPEHEETPENR',
  58: 'SVSNAATR',
  59: 'GFSQQEVQFEPELFHNTIVCEKPNNHLNK',
  60: 'GAHIMNSTCAAMPK',
  61: 'SDLGPSYGGWQVLDATPQER',
  62: 'NEDACPVGTVSAAPWGSSSILPISWAYIK',
  63: 'VLLEPLRPWACPR',
  64: 'DSMTTENGK',
  65: 'SSSYADPWTPPR',
  66: 'VEDSHQILSQTSHDLNECSWSLNILAINKPQNK',
  67: 'FLASVLPACGDLSFQQDQMTQTFGFR',
  68: 'LHLQQHVSMEFLK',
  69: 'MSNTQAER',
  70: 'SALIVHQR',
  71: 'TPELHLSGK',
  72: 'EAFLSDR',
  73: 'LYILFAAPPEK',
  74: 'EKPFACTECGK',
  75: 'AHCGPAELCEFYSR',
  76: 'STDTSCQMAGLR',
  77: 'GMLEPVQRPDVVLMGAGYR',
  78: 'STLFLIPLFGIHYIIFNFLPDNAGLGIR',
  79: 'NASGHTGDR',
  80: 'NLTVSVHVSPVEGLCLAGGGGLAQQVLVPAGSARPVAFSVVPTAAAAVSLK',
  81: 'DLHFDPSNAVVHVGGVLCVEITMYSQMPVPVHVEQIVVNVHFSIEK',
  82: 'ETGLCADFHPSGAVVAVGLNTGR',
  83: 'LIQPHVQASNNCWEEAISQVDK',
  84: 'HLNSILVLDLR',
  85: 'CQEQAQTTDWR',
  86: 'HGYMIVGDPMGGK',
  87: 'LNVPQVLLPFGR',
  88: 'SASACSTPTHTPQDSLTGVGGDVQEAFAQSSR',
  89: 'MHFFNVPEPDGHIISPLLAGFYMFWTMIILLQVLIPISLYVSIEIVK',
  90: 'LFGPGFANSSWSWVAPEGAGCR',
  91: 'GGSAPGPDPSCWFDPNNICGGGLEPGLVFLGFLLVVGMGLAGAFLAHYVR',
  92: 'AGYEGDGTLCSEMDPCTGLTPGGCSR',
  93: 'FMPLDQWLYFDALDCLPEDGELLPSPEDCALR',
  94: 'VCFNLGR',
  95: 'NLSPTPASPNQGPPPQVPVSPGPPK',
  96: 'SAHALLLPDDPPCHDLGCHPVLTVSWVLGCTLALVVSAFFVLNHLWLWAQACCSHR',
  97: 'QGVLAVIDAYNTSNK',
  98: 'DLEMFAR',
  99: 'GFCMSTLR',
  100: 'YGVIYSTPLPEK'}
}
```

**Here is the custom function that isn't working:**

```
def ButcherShop(df, target, rule, min_length=7,exception=None,max_legnth=100, pH=2.0):
    raw = df[target]
    string_catcher=re.compile(r'^([A-Z]+)$')
    unique_peptides = set()
    for peptide in raw:
        new_peptides = parser.cleave(peptide, rule=rule,min_length=min_length,exception=exception)
        unique_peptides.update(new_peptides)
    print(f'Done,{len(unique_peptides)} sequences of >= 7 amino acids!')
    pep_dic = [{'sequence': i} for i in unique_peptides]
    pep_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(pep_dic)
    for i, row in pep_df.iterrows():
        unique_id = i
        peptides = row['sequence']
        pep_dic['parsed_sequence'] = re.findall(string_catcher,peptides)
        pep_dic['xlength'] = len(peptides)
        pep_dic['charge'] = int(round(electrochem.charge(peptides, pH=pH)))
        pep_dic['mass']=int(round(Peptide_mass(peptides)))
    pep_dic = [peptide for peptide in pep_dic if peptide['length'] <= int(max_length)]
    return unique_peptides,pep_dic, pep_df
```

I would greatly appreciate any help I can get on this.

**UPDATED SOLUTION:**

```
def ButcherShop(df, target, rule, min_length=7,exception=None,max_length=100, pH=2.0):
    raw = df[target]
    string_catcher=re.compile(r'^([A-Z]+)$')
    unique_peptides = set()
    for peptide in raw:
        new_peptides = parser.cleave(peptide, rule=rule,min_length=min_length,exception=exception)
        unique_peptides.update(new_peptides)
    print(f'Done,{len(unique_peptides)} sequences of >= 7 amino acids!')
    pep_dic = [{'sequence': i} for i in unique_peptides]
    for row in pep_dic:
        peptides = row['sequence']
        row['parsed_sequence'] = re.findall(string_catcher,peptides)
        row['length'] = len(peptides)
        row['charge'] = int(round(electrochem.charge(peptides, pH=pH)))
        row['mass']=int(round(Peptide_Mass(peptides)))
    pep_dic = [peptide for peptide in pep_dic if peptide['length'] <= int(max_length)]
    pep_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(pep_dic)
    return unique_peptides,pep_dic, pep_df
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pep_dic` is a list of dictionaries, not a single dictionary. You need to loop over it, not loop over the dataframe.

Also, you're assigning the `xlength` key of the dictionaries, but then checking `length` when you filter it at the end. One of them needs to be changed so they're consistent.

```
for row in pep_dic:
    peptides = row['sequence']
    row['parsed_sequence'] = re.findall(string_catcher,peptides)
    row['length'] = len(peptides)
    row['charge'] = int(round(electrochem.charge(peptides, pH=pH)))
    row['mass']=int(round(Peptide_mass(peptides)))

pep_dic = [peptide for peptide in pep_dic if peptide['length'] <= int(max_length)]
```

Comment: great catch!  Thank you. looping over a list of dictionaries makes sense now, I am just starting to use them more. I appreciate all that I can learn!

Comment: TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str .... it is throwing this error at peptides = row['sequence'].  is it not better to use pep_df['sequece'] instead of df.iterrows()?

Comment: I don't really know pandas well, I assumed that part was OK.

Comment: I don't really understand why you need both `pep_df` and `pep_dic`. Don't they both contain the same peptide strings?

Comment: I don't need to, ideally i would like to iterate over a list of dictionaries. I am creating a df for downstream analyses. the function is set to produce a set, a list of dictionaries, and a dataframe.

Comment: I've gotten rid of `pep_df` in the loop, try it now.

Comment: I think you mean for row in pep_dic.values(): ..... that didn't work but it appears `` for row in pep_dic:``  works. I will confirm your answer when I fix a bug on the electrochem function.

Comment: All good, i think it is working now. I am correcting a bunch of my own typos from functions within this function.